# Get concatenated text of elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I tried it with `getElementById` and it worked. But now I want the same with multiple `div`'s so I have to use classes. So I changed the method to `getElementsByClassName` and now it says undefined.

(The function is called when a option in a select changes. This works correctly)

HTML:

```
 <div class="item_content">
 <h3  class="filmnaam">22 jump street</h3> 
 </div>
 <div class="item_content">
 <h3 class="filmnaam">rio 2</h3>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function sorting(sortingway) {
  alert(sortingway.value);
  var titelfilms = document.getElementsByClassName("filmnaam");
  var titels = titelfilms.innerHTML;
  console.log(titels[0]);
}
```

Is there a way to do this without jQuery?

Comment: It's probably easy to miss the fact that every one of JQuery's values is actually a collection - often with a single element. When you're writing more basic JS yourself, you just need to recognize which values are going to come back as single elements (`byId`) or as a NodeList (`byClassName`)

Comment: How will you call the function?

Comment: @pianoman99 the function is already called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, so loop that!

```
var titelfilms = document.getElementsByClassName("filmnaam");
for (var i = 0; i < titelfilms.length; i++) {
    var titels = titelfilms[i].innerHTML;
    console.log(titels);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`titelfilms` is a node list, you can't get the `innerHTML` of a node list as a whole, it contains multiple references to elements which each have their own individual property.

You could loop through and concatenate each `innerHTML` onto a variable, or you could [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the `innerHTML` of your returned elements to an array and then [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them up:

```js
function sorting(sortingway) {
    var titelfilms = document.getElementsByClassName("filmnaam");
    var titels = Array.prototype.map.call(titelfilms, function (el) {
        return el.innerHTML;
    }).join(' ');
    console.log(titels);
}

sorting();
```

```html
<div class="item_content">
     <h3 class="filmnaam">22 jump street</h3> 
</div>
<div class="item_content">
     <h3 class="filmnaam">rio 2</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah also a nice solution... but a bit hard for me since i'm a starting programmer anyway thank u!